# Implements covolutional neural network in feature extraction

Tags: image-processing, machine-learning, computer-vision

I've just read the convolutional neural network in feature extraction, but it's really abstract. I want to understand it more clearly, i have to implement it. However, i don't know how to implements it!! Do you have any suggestion? Can somebody give me a Pseudocode? Thanks you all! Any suggestion is welcom!

Answer (score 5):

Here is an example I've found with a quick web search:

- http://www.codeproject.com/KB/library/NeuralNetRecognition.aspx